# How do I get a button used on multiple card containers to only affect one container at a time?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am currently working on a web application using angular and angular material. The page in question holds several profiles each with a button that when clicked removes the information currently showing and replaces it with the rest of the profile information. The issue is that when I click this button on one profile it does this information flip on all the profiles at once. I need help figuring out how to have the button only affect the profile it is associated with.

I am still relatively new to coding, so I've mainly been doing research on advice on how to approach this particular situation, but nothing I've found so far has worked.

```
  <mat-card class="bpBuddyCont" *ngFor= "let profile of profileList">
    <div>
      <ul class="bpBuddies">
        <li class="li2">
          <div *ngIf="!showHiddenInfo">
            <mat-card-title class="specifics">{{profile.dogName}}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle class="subtitle">Owner ~ {{profile.ownerFirstName}}</mat-card-subtitle>
            <mat-card-subtitle>Member Since {{profile.yearJoined}}</mat-card-subtitle>
          </div>
              <div class="column4" *ngIf="showHiddenInfo">
                <span class="details4">Additional Notes: </span>
                <span class="details3">{{profile.additionalNotes}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          <button mat-button color="primary" class="btn" (click)="showHiddenInfo = !showHiddenInfo">{{showHiddenInfo ? 'Back' : 'More...'}}</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON for `profileList`>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the profile object with
profile.showHiddenInfo and set it as false initially.

For this in your js(most probably the component file) after getting profileList,

```
  profileList.forEach((profile, index) => {
         angular.extend(profile, {showHiddenInfo: false});
         //not sure about this angular.extend but you need to extend your object here
  });
```

Now when the button is clicked replace showHiddenInfo, i.e.

```
profile.showHiddenInfo = !profile.showHiddenInfo;
```

And Replace

```
*ngIf="showHiddenInfo"
```

with

```
*ngIf="profile.showHiddenInfo"
```

Comment: yes!! This did the trick! I actually only ended up needing to update the `*ngIf="profile.showHiddenInfo"` and the button click with `profile.showHiddenInfo = !profile.showHiddenInfo;`. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using one boolean variable for each object, as `profile.isExpanded` and on click change it as like:

```
(click)="profile.isExpanded = !profile.isExpanded"
```

HTML Code:

```
<mat-card class="bpBuddyCont" *ngFor="let profile of profileList">
    <div>
        <ul class="bpBuddies">
            <li class="li2">
                <div *ngIf="!profile.isExpanded">
                    <mat-card-title class="specifics">{{profile.dogName}}</mat-card-title>
                    <mat-card-subtitle class="subtitle">Owner ~ {{profile.ownerFirstName}}</mat-card-subtitle>
                    <mat-card-subtitle>Member Since {{profile.yearJoined}}</mat-card-subtitle>
                </div>
                <div class="column4" *ngIf="profile.isExpanded">
                    <span class="details4">Additional Notes: </span>
                <span class="details3">{{profile.additionalNotes}}</span>
              </div>
          <button mat-button color="primary" class="btn" (click)="profile.isExpanded = !profile.isExpanded">{{profile.isExpanded ? 'Back' : 'More...'}}</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
```

No change in TS file.

[`WORKING STACKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnfct7)

Comment: I think this is similar to what I ended up doing with the above comment's advice, and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @X2coding Glad it helps..!